# How to avoid multiple or(||) for null validation in java, springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have three input from user

String key1
String key2
String key3

Users can pass exactly one key at a time as input. I am validating it as below.

In my code, I am checking

```
if(key1 == null && key2 == null && key3 == null){
      throw new Exception("invalid input");
}else if((null != key1 && null != key2) || (null != key2 && null != key3) || (null != key1 && null != key3)){
    throw new Exception("invalid input");
}
```

Can we avoid these `or` conditions? May be using `Java-8`?

Any thoughts/suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Note: I have a JUnit test code in place, so I need to reduce the number of test cases as well.

Comment: The last remark makes no sense. Regardless of how you implement it, the unit test should always be the same. It’s the *contract* that defines the eight scenarios regarding which values can be null, not the implementation.

Comment: I agree with you, but if we reduce the number of combination somehow then our test cases also get reduced.

Comment: The number of combinations is not reducible. There are three inputs, each of them can be `null`, which makes eight combinations. The implementation can’t change how you test it, as otherwise, you would pervert the entire purpose of unit tests. Your unit test should not make any assumptions about the implementation, except that it has to fulfill the contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the stream api this can be done like this:

```
int count = Stream.of(key1, key2, key3).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
if(count != 1) {
  throw new Exception("invalid input");
}
```

Comment: `Stream.of(key1, key2, key3).filter(Objects::nonNull).count()` would be better.

Comment: You would have to check if `count != 0` and not if it`s greater than 0.

Comment: Question said *"Users can pass **exactly** one key"*, so check should be `count != 1`

Comment: `e->e!=null` means that compiler must create a hidden method with the lambda expression, which is unnecessary, since the Java Runtime Library already has a method doing that check, so you can use that method instead, as already shown in my first comment.

Comment: Nah, you're the one who thought of using Stream in the first place. I just helped get it a bit better. 

Comment: Thank you @f1sh for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of non-null values, by using the `? :` ternary conditional operator.

```java
if ((key1 != null ? 1 : 0) + (key2 != null ? 1 : 0) + (key3 != null ? 1 : 0) != 1)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exactly one of key1, key2, and key3 must be given");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But to get the 100% test code coverage we need to write more test cases of each combination.

Comment: @SSK why is that requirement a problem with this answer?

Comment: @SSK Wouldn't you need to do that anyway, to make sure the code works correctly? Test all 8 possible combinations?

Comment: I have added the note in question, to  keep test cases as minimum as possible Thanks :)

Comment: @SSK Anything less than 8 test cases is an incomplete test. Code coverage reports might help find missing test cases, but 100% code coverage doesn't mean your test cases are fully encompassing. If you believe so, then you are sorely mistaken.

Comment: In fact, less than 100% code coverage does not necessarily imply incomplete testing either.

Comment: @Holger That is correct. Some conditions may be impossible to cause, but the guard condition is written anyway, because it's good to be comprehensible, according to [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) design principles.

Comment: Indeed, that’s the whole point of `assert` statements, for example. But there are also things like `default:` labels, the compiler mandates, despite we know that all cases have been handled or code to be inserted after a method we know to never return normally (throw unconditionally, block forever, or exit the JVM), the code after a search loop that can never fail, etc. Sometimes, it’s much simpler to implement a logic by handling all cases straight-forwardly, even when we know that not all cases apply. We also don’t need to test whether each try-with-resource does `addSuppressed` correctly…

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe count the strings who are not `null` and check if this number is equal to 1.

```
int notNullStrings = 0;
if(key1 != null) notNullStrings++;
if(key2 != null) notNullStrings++;
if(key3 != null) notNullStrings++;
if(notNullStrings != 1) {
    throw new Exception("invalid input");
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to validate your input parameters explicitly, Spring forbids null-injection by default. See `@Value` for more [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html).

```
    @Value("${key1:default}")
    private String withDefault;

    @Value("${key2}")
    private String required;

    @Nullable
    @Value("${key3:#{null}}")
    private String nullable;
```